# Error with nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu-13.10

I am trying to use `express` in an ubuntu 13.10 distribution.  I am using `node version 0.10.29` and `npm 1.4.14`  When I use `express` this is my output:

```
    module.js:340
       throw err;
      ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'mkdirp'
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
      at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
      at require (module.js:380:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/bin/express:10:14)
      at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
      at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Additionally, I have to use `sudo npm` as `npm` doesn't work (i'm not sure if that's part of the issue - but I suspect path issues, not really sure).  I have googled but haven't been able to fix the issues.

Edit:  I think I messed up my path.  I am unable to reinstall npm.  Here is output from `$PATH`

`bash: /home/qtrain/npm/bin:/usr/bin/yo:/home/qtrain/.node/bin:/home/qtrain/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/qtrain/.rvm/bin:/home/qtrain/.rvm/bin:/home/qtrain/.rvm/bin:`

Comment: Is `mkdirp` installed? `sudo npm install mkdirp`. And if it already is installed, does your node process owner have permission to read it?

Comment: `npm` should not need root at all unless you are trying to bind to a lower port (ex 80). What error do you get? Haven't you forgot to run `npm install` inside your project dir?

Comment: `mkdirp` is installed.  Not sure how to check process owner...

Comment: @Salem getting errors when I run `npm install` additionally, I have to run it as `sudo npm install` for some reason.  errors include `cannot open /../../package.json` and `couldn't read dependencies`  additionally I have to run `nodejs` instead of `node` b/c of a system conflict.  Not sure if this is messing everything up

Comment: Supposing your express project is placed in `/a/b/c`, try to run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /a/b/c` and then `npm install` and `nodejs your_main_script.js`. If you get any errors post them, don't use sudo.

Comment: @Salem tried your instructions to no avail - I am unable to run npm w/o sudo.  I think I messed up my path.  I tried to reinstall node and npm from scratch and node installed correctly but npm gave me an error `unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`  I am going to post my path output in hopes that someone can help me repair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mkdirp` error seems to originate from using the `chris-lea repo for node.js` as Michael answered.

To fix: eliminate the PPA and node itself, then reinstall as below.

1.) `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`  - if you don't already have it

2.) `sudo ppa-purge ppa:chris-lea/node.js`

3.) `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`

4.) `sudo apt-get remove npm`

5.) `sudo apt-get autoremove`

6.) `sudo apt-get install nodejs`

7.) `sudo apt-get install npm`

8.) `sudo apt-get install node-express`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem while using npm and express.  My solution was to uninstall node from my entire system using `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`

Then I reinstalled node from source following directions here http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001808/ch01.html#chap5_id35941617

Then I had to install npm separately using `sudo apt-get install npm` but it still didn't work.

It was then that I realized that ppa repos I had installed from chris lea were not configured for 13.10

https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/node.js-legacy

Removed them and reinstalled npm using `sudo apt-get install npm` and installed express with `sudo apt-get install node-express`

I was then able to use npm and express

Hope this helps..